# Issues transferring zone file with dnspython

Tags: python, python-2.7, dns

I am attempting to use python to pull down a zone file. After going through hoards of documentation, I am still stuck on one line of code:

dns.zone.from_xfr(dns.query.xfr('3.211.54.86','megacorpone.com'))

I get the following error:

socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused

I've hardcoded ns2.megacorpone.com's IP to isolate any problems. For some reason this connection continues to refuse. Is anyone able to shed some light on this problem?

Thanks all

Comment: Are you sure you are allowed to perform a zone transfer from that server? Try `dig axfr megacorpone.com @3.211.54.86` at the command line to see if you are.

Comment: Interesting I can perform a zone transfer using the domain name (ns2.megacorpone.com) but NOT the ip address. that's very interesting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the same command with the domain name instead of IP worked.

Comment: That's because it's `3.211.51.86`, not `54.86`.

Comment: yeah i must have fatfingered it, late night studying...